# How to select rows from one table, when join matches multiple rows?

Tags: sql, oracle

The scenario is as follows: I have these two tables:

```
(TABLE1)
SUPER_ID| NAME |
-------+--
1 | BOB  |


(TABLE2)
ID| SUPER_ID |
-------+----+
1 | 1       |
2 | 1       |
3 | 1       |
```

If I join these two tables as

```
`SELECT a.super_id, a.name 
   FROM TABLE1 a LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE2 b ON a.super_id = b.super_id 
  WHERE a.super_id = 1`
```

The result will be

```
SUPER_ID| NAME |
-------+--------
1       | BOB  |
1       | BOB  |
1       | BOB  |
```

How can I select only the rows from TABLE1 without using a GROUP BY? Thanks

UPDATE: Ok, so I have a 3rd table...

```
(TABLE3)
ID| TYPE |
-------+----+
1 | A       |
2 | B       |
3 | C       |
```

which I need to Join to TABLE2 AS:

```
SELECT a.super_id, a.name 
  FROM TABLE1 a INNER JOIN 
       TABLE2 b ON a.super_id = b.super_id INNER JOIN
       TABLE3 c ON b.id = c.id
 WHERE a.super_id = 1
```

Comment: What's the relationship of TABLE2 and TABLE3? 1:M? N:M? Please post some data for it. For future reference please frame your questions in a minimal but complete fashion. Iterative extraction of details and refinements just wastes everybody's time.

Comment: Please take a few minutes to understand joins and how they work: https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/  since you want to join 3 tables... what does your expected result set look like?

Comment: Thanks for your response @xQber; I manage to accomplish my request by using a sub-query in the FROM clause; as suggested by @Charles Bretana. I was trying to limit my result set based on TAABLE1, regardless of having multiple matches in TABLE2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by restricting the join based on some other [unique] criterion. And the SQL syntax of course depends on what other criterion you choose. Say you want the latest record entered, If the table has a timestamp column you could do this:

```
SELECT a.super_id, a.name 
FrOM TABLE1 a LEFT JOIN TABLE2 b 
  ON b.super_id = a.super_id 
     and b.timestamp = (Select Max(timestamp)
                        From TABLE2 
                        Where super_id = a.super_id)
WHERE a.super_id = 1
```

If you don't have a timestamp, but you have a unique index or key (looks like `id` is such), you could use that:

```
SELECT a.super_id, a.name 
FrOM TABLE1 a LEFT JOIN TABLE2 b 
  ON b.super_id = a.super_id 
     and b.id= (Select Max(id)
                From TABLE2 
                Where super_id = a.super_id)
WHERE a.super_id = 1
```

Comment: Thanks; I ended up using your approach (the first one). Instead of using Max(), I used DISTINCT() and works grate!

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do it.

I assume you want rows from table1 if you have super_id in table2.

You can use EXISTS

```
SELECT a.super_id, a.name 
FROM TABLE1 a 
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT NULL FROM table2 b WHERE a.super_id = b.super_id )
AND a.super_id = 1
```

---

**UPDATE**

You can use GROUP BY into a WITH clause.

```
WITH single_b AS ( SELECT super_id, name 
                   FROM table2
                   GROUP BY super_id, name )
SELECT a.super_id, a.name 
FROM TABLE1 a INNER JOIN single_b b ON a.super_id = b.super_id 
              INNER JOIN TABLE3 c ON b.super_id = c.id
WHERE a.super_id = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. The thing is that I need to Join a 3rd table (TABLE3) as INNER JOIN TABLE3 c ON b.ID = c.ID...